# How to make math with datetime inside models?

Tags: python, django-models

I'v been trying to add 10 days in a django model.

I want to make this everytime a data is created in the DB.

```
expiration = 10
expiration_at = date of creation + expiration
```

[image: example]

**EDITED**

After some codes from comments. I got this so far.

```
class Certificados(models.Model):
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
description = models.TextField(null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
expiration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
expiration_at = models.DateTimeField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.expiration_at = self.created_at + timedelta(days=self.expiration)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Certificados'
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

This code now brings me this error.
[image: Error]
Someone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll want to use `timedelta()` from the `datetime` package.

```py
from datetime import timedelta

expiration = timedelta(days=10)
expiration_at += expiration
```

---

Another approach could be to use the `arrow` package:

> Arrow is a Python library that offers a sensible and human-friendly approach to creating, manipulating, formatting and converting dates, times and timestamps.

One way to achieve this in arrow would be with `arrow.utcnow().shift(days=10).datetime`. Notice I'm using `utcnow()` here; this is because working with any other date timezone will lead to massive headaches, so I'd recommend working with UTC if you can :). If you need a specific timezone, I'd recommend reading the [arrow docs](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to learn more.

Comment: If i do this, wont be a Django model, its just going to be a normal variable. right?

Comment: Since Django [DateTimeField](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s are represented in python as `datetime.datetime` fields, the `+=` operation will work with `timedelta`.

Comment: This may be overkill to write out, but make sure you call the `save()` method on your ORM object afterwards for the changes to take effect in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the expiration time to be adjustable post-creation, you'd need to save the creation time too.

You can then derive the expiry time in e.g. `save()`:

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import now


class Thing(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    expiry_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.expiry_time = self.creation_time + datetime.timedelta(days=self.expiry_days)
        super().__save__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: "datetime.timedelta(days=expiry_days)" should use "datetime.timedelta(days=self.expiry_days)" instead?

Comment: @AlexandreSiedschlag Yes, typo. Fixed :)

Comment: I tried this code and got this error: "This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Certificados.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the CertificadosSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly."....do i need something else for your code to work?

Comment: i'v made some changes on the post. Would you mind checking it?